# Gradle Android - Test coverage on legacy test projects structure

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

I am migrating a quite big and complex legacy project to Gradle. 
I have many libraries projects, where each project has its own test subprojects.
The project structure looks as follows:

```
- LibraryX
-- LibraryXTestsOne
-- LibraryXTestsTwo
- LibraryY
-- LibraryYTests 
....
```

Each library is configured as follows:

1. The main sourceset contains all the library code
2. The androidTest sourceset is empty

Each test project is configured as follows:

1. It lists the parent library as a dependency
2. The main sourceset is empty
3. The androidTest sourceset contains all the tests code

With such a configuration I manage to run the test with :libraryTestsA:connectedAndroidTest, but I can't get the test coverage to work. I enable it through

```
buildTypes{
   debug{ testCoverageEnabled true }
}
```

Apparently the classes of the parent library are not instrumented causing the code coverage to be zero.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you just need to set `testCoverageEnabled` to `true` for all the projects/libraries that the test project depends on. 
That will be enough to instrument your code.

You still need to create a custom *jacocoReport* task though, since the one provided by the android plugin looks up classes and sources in the project main sourceset, which are empty in a configuration like mine.